# How to apply a function to each row of a dataframe and get the results back

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

This is my data Frame

```
            3        4        5        6       97       98       99      100
0         1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0     95.0     96.0     97.0     98.0
1     50699.0  16302.0  50700.0  16294.0  50735.0  16334.0  50737.0  16335.0
2     57530.0  33436.0  57531.0  33438.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
3     24014.0  24015.0  34630.0  24016.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4     44933.0   2611.0  44936.0   2612.0  44982.0   2631.0  44972.0   2633.0
1792  46712.0  35340.0  46713.0  35341.0  46759.0  35387.0  46760.0  35388.0
1793  61283.0  40276.0  61284.0  40277.0  61330.0  40323.0  61331.0  40324.0
1794      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1795      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1796  27156.0  48331.0  27157.0  48332.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

--> How do I apply the below function and get the answers back for each row in one run...
**values is the array of values of each row and N is 100**

```
def entropy_s(values, N):
    a= scipy.stats.entropy(values,base=2)
    a = round(a,2)
    global CONSTANT_COUNT,RANDOM_COUNT,LOCAL_COUNT,GLOBAL_COUNT,ODD_COUNT
    if(math.isnan(a) == True):
        a = 0.0
    if(a==0.0):
        CONSTANT_COUNT += 1
    elif(a<round(math.log2(N),2)):
        LOCAL_COUNT +=1
        RANDOM_COUNT +=1
    elif(a==round(math.log2(N),2)):
            RANDOM_COUNT +=1
            GLOBAL_COUNT += 1
            LOCAL_COUNT += 1
    else:
        ODD_COUNT +=1
```

Comment: use [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method: you can pass in input a custom function and you can specify in which axis the function is applied

Comment: @MPizzotti thanks but I tried the same but it is not working quite well !

Comment: i'm not sure what this function actualy does to the dataframe itself. if you use the function entropy_s() to modify the values of the dataframe there is not better way to do this.
one possible solution is to do a small refactor on the function itself.
But if the function does not change the dataframe and it just takes the values and applies some logic, i think that you can simply use a loop for iterate over each row and use counters... i don't think that is possible to get the answer back for all rows in one single run

Comment: @MPizzotti so in the function values parameter is each row as an array of values  and it calculates the entropy of the whole array. So basically I want it to read the dataframe convert each row to an array of values and calculate entropy of each row basically each array automatically in like one run

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the values are supposed to be rows? in that case, I suggest the following:
rows will be fed to function and you can get the column in each row using row.column_name.

```
def func(N=100):
  def entropy_s(values):
    a= scipy.stats.entropy(values,base=2)
    a = round(a,2)
    global CONSTANT_COUNT,RANDOM_COUNT,LOCAL_COUNT,GLOBAL_COUNT,ODD_COUNT
    if(math.isnan(a) == True):
        a = 0.0
    if(a==0.0):
        CONSTANT_COUNT += 1
    elif(a<round(math.log2(N),2)):
        LOCAL_COUNT +=1
        RANDOM_COUNT +=1
    elif(a==round(math.log2(N),2)):
            RANDOM_COUNT +=1
            GLOBAL_COUNT += 1
            LOCAL_COUNT += 1
    else:
        ODD_COUNT +=1
  return entropy_s


df.apply(func(100), axis=1)
```

if you want to have the rows as list you can do this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: func(100)([k for k in x]), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks but I want it row wise so for each row like each row is an array like ['0', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0......, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0, 99.0]
... now I want to apply the function to these basically to each row

Comment: this also didn't work ``` df.apply(lambda x: func(100)([k for k in x]), axis=1)``` ?what is the error? Isn't it probably because of the NaN's

Comment: no I made sure to ignore the NaNs ..but still running into quite a few errors :(

Answer (score -1):

```
import functools
series = df.apply(functool.partial(entropy_s, N=100), axis=1)
# or 
series = df.apply(lambda x: entropy_s(x, N=100), axis=1)
```

`axis=1` will push the rows of your `df` to the first arg of `apply`.

You will get a `pd.Series` of `None`'s though, because your function doesn't return anything.

I highly suggest to avoid using globals in your function.

EDIT: If you want meaningful help, you need to ask meaningful questions. Which errors are you getting?

Here is a quick and dirty example that demonstrates what I've suggested. If you have an error, your function likely has a bug (for example, it doesn't return anything), or it doesn't know how to handle NaN.

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [6, 7, 8]})

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   1  2  3
0  1  3  6
1  2  4  7
2  3  5  8

In [8]: df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x), axis=1)
Out[8]:
0    10
1    13
2    16
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks so much.. but it dint work quite well.. thousands of errors..If you can guide please

Comment: @SSS311 see edit, but you need to provide more info

Comment: so in the function values parameter is each row as an array of values and it calculates the entropy of the whole array. So basically I want it to read the dataframe convert each row to an array of values and calculate entropy of each row basically each array automatically in like one run

Comment: That's what apply does. A problem with your code is that `entropy_s` doesn't return anything. I made a dummy example of showing that this is what df.apply does: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
Notice how my exaple returns the sum of each row?